# USB webcamera is not working even though ret and frame are returning values

Tags: camera, augmented-reality, camera-calibration, calibration, aruco

I was working on a project where I need to measure the distance between two markers.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

**the "ret" = true
the frame =. is also giving values. **

But the thing is I am not getting any output.
TMI(if needed) : Yes, this was my usb webcamera  ret and frame values

**My expected output is distance = x **

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What values are you getting in `frame`? Please add more details.
Also note that your webcam may need some time to start grabbing frames.

Comment: @decadenza Hi, the camera is able to grab the frames but the thing is it's capturing mirror reflection, and not the object itself. Example: It  is capturing my reflection from the mirror, but when I move my camera towards me, it is not able to detect me.